# where oracle foreign key constraint named SYS_C comming from

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys

my database is oracle 10.2 and my create table sql is like this:

```
create table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
(
  company_id      NUMBER not null,
  company_name    VARCHAR2(30),
  company_address VARCHAR2(100),
  is_in_use       VARCHAR2(1),
  is_canceled     VARCHAR2(1),
  is_headquarter  VARCHAR2(1),
  account_id      NUMBER not null
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  maxtrans 255
storage
  (
initial 64K
minextents 1
maxextents unlimited
);

alter table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
  add constraint PK_ESHOP_SYS_COMPANY primary key (COMPANY_ID)
  using index 
  tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
alter table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
  add constraint FK_SYS_COMPANY_PAY_ACCOUNT foreign key (ACCOUNT_ID)
 references T_EP_PAY_ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID);
```

but in my database,I have to 2 FKs on column "account_id":

```
owner       constraint_name          table_name      column_name  position
ESHOPV2  SYS_C009725                T_EP_SYS_COMPANY    ACCOUNT_ID    null
ESHOPV2  FK_SYS_COMPANY_PAY_ACCOUNT T_EP_SYS_COMPANY    ACCOUNT_ID     1
```

why there are 2 FKs? I did rename the table name,dose the rename ddl has something to do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't both foreign key constraints. [The SYS_C is a system-generated name for a constraint you didn't explicitly name](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2891); in this case for your not-null check. You can see those immediately after the create:

```
create table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
(
  company_id      NUMBER not null,
  company_name    VARCHAR2(30),
  company_address VARCHAR2(100),
  is_in_use       VARCHAR2(1),
  is_canceled     VARCHAR2(1),
  is_headquarter  VARCHAR2(1),
  account_id      NUMBER not null
);

select uc.constraint_name, uc.constraint_type, ucc.column_name, ucc.position
from user_constraints uc
join user_cons_columns ucc on ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
where uc.table_name = 'T_EP_SYS_COMPANY';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE COLUMN_NAME     POSITION
------------------------------ --------------- --------------- --------
SYS_C0093988                   C               COMPANY_ID               
SYS_C0093989                   C               ACCOUNT_ID
```

The constraint type is C, showing it's a check constraint. You can name those by explicitly adding check constraints rather than specifying them as 'not null' but there is no real benefit - you don't ever need to refer to them by name, e.g. to temporarily disable them.

After you add the primary and foreign key you see those too:

```
alter table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
  add constraint PK_ESHOP_SYS_COMPANY primary key (COMPANY_ID);

alter table T_EP_SYS_COMPANY
  add constraint FK_SYS_COMPANY_PAY_ACCOUNT foreign key (ACCOUNT_ID)
 references T_EP_PAY_ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_ID);

select uc.constraint_name, uc.constraint_type, ucc.column_name, ucc.position
from user_constraints uc
join user_cons_columns ucc on ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
where uc.table_name = 'T_EP_SYS_COMPANY';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                CONSTRAINT_TYPE COLUMN_NAME     POSITION
------------------------------ --------------- --------------- --------
SYS_C0093988                   C               COMPANY_ID               
SYS_C0093989                   C               ACCOUNT_ID               
PK_ESHOP_SYS_COMPANY           P               COMPANY_ID             1 
FK_SYS_COMPANY_PAY_ACCOUNT     R               ACCOUNT_ID             1
```

These have constraint type P and R, for 'primary key' and 'referential integrity'.

Read more about [types of integrity constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/data_int.htm#i3790) and [how they are shown in the data dictionary](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1037.htm).

Comment: Thanks for your help,I never thought of that.So if I create a table with a not null column,and create a primary constraint,I get 2 constraints,one is check constraint,another is primary constraint.But if I create a table with a primary key,I just get 1 primary constraint.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> owner       constraint_name          table_name      column_name  position
> ESHOPV2  SYS_C009725                T_EP_SYS_COMPANY    ACCOUNT_ID    null
> ESHOPV2  FK_SYS_COMPANY_PAY_ACCOUNT T_EP_SYS_COMPANY    ACCOUNT_ID     1
> ```
>
> why there are 2 FKs?

**SYS_C009725** is not a foreign key constraint. It is a **CHECK constraint** for the **NOT NULL** condition. If you see the **CONSTRAINT_TYPE** then you would see it as `C`. And the name as **SYS_C** you see is because it is **system-generated name**.

Too keep it simple, let's see a small example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER NOT NULL
  3  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT constraint_name,
  2    constraint_type,
  3    table_name,
  4    search_condition
  5  FROM user_constraints
  6  WHERE table_name ='T';

CONSTRAINT_NAME CONSTRAINT_TYPE TABLE_NAME SEARCH_CONDITION
--------------- --------------- ---------- ----------------
SYS_C0010726    C               T          "ID" IS NOT NULL

SQL>
```